# Simple triangle with VBO and IBO - OpenGL ES 2.0 (Android)

Tags: java, android

I have being looking for a simple example in Android of a simple triangle being drawn using glDrawElements with a VBO for vertex position and solid color storage and IBO for the triangle index storage, but i've being unable to find one.

I have found some examples of triangles with VBO and of more complex forms being drawn with VBO / IBO, but i haven't found any examples of just a simple straightforward triangle.

Could someone please provide a very simple example of a rendered with this?